# Laravel - Mass Assignment Exception error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to save multiple rows to a table, however, I am presented with a `Mass Assignment Error`.

The error is: `Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException criteria_id`

```
$criteria->save();

    $criteria_id = $criteria->id;

     foreach(Input::get('bedrooms') as $bedroom){
        $new_bedroom=array(
            'criteria_id' => $criteria->id,
            'bedroom' => $bedroom,
            );
        $bedroom = new Bedroom($new_bedroom);
        $bedroom->save();
    }
```

My database structure is:

[image: screenshot]

so there isn't any incorrect spelling. The criteria_id comes from the variable from the recently saved criteria (see code above forloop).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `criteria_id` in the `$fillable` array of the model?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, no it isn't. The array is empty. I have to access the variable later on in the code which works perfectly fine, that is inside a `foreach` loop also. - `->attach($criteria_id)`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To be able to set properties by passing them to the model's constructor, you need to list all the properties you need in the `$fillable` array. As mentioned in the [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

```
class Bedroom extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('criteria_id', 'bedroom');
}
```

Also you can use the `create` method if you want. It creates a new model and saves it directly:

```
foreach(Input::get('bedrooms') as $bedroom){
    $new_bedroom=array(
        'criteria_id' => $criteria->id,
        'bedroom' => $bedroom,
        );
    $bedroom = Bedroom::create($new_bedroom);
}
```

Comment: never knew eloquent just like ruby on rails `attr_accessible`

Answer (score 14):

The **inverse** of what lukas said is "guarded".  Instead of "white-listing" fields, you could just declare which are guarded.

For example:

```
class Bedroom extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

This was more useful for me because I didn't really care about most fields.

Gotten from the docs for Laravel 5.2 but I assume it works on older versions.

To allow any fields, you could just provide an empty array:

```
class Bedroom extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in the Model that you want to store your data on that table.
Suppose your table is bedrooms and you created model is Bedroom which is located in the `app` folder.

In your case, you have to store data in `$criteria_id` and `$bedroom`, so you should add these two fields to the model in the following way.

```
class Bedroom extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = ['criteria_id', 'bedroom'];
}
```