# Laravel Mass Assignment Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have tried multiple troubleshooting steps on this site about this error. Already added a `$fillable` and updated with composer but I am still getting the same error. Here is a screen shot of the error that I am experiencing and the codes for my `Model.php`.

[Laravel Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqvpG.png)

[Model Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BblZ9.png)

Comment: You don't have $fillable property in your model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Mass Assignment Exception error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724117/laravel-mass-assignment-exception-error)

Comment: Can you  please upload model and error message in question again ? Because links don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you:

```
protected $fillable = ['body'];
```

in your model? If not add that property to your model.

Answer (score 1):

As per [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) for **Mass Assignment**, you should define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. You may do this using the **$fillable** property on the model.

```
 protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

Comment: I have added the code and I'm still getting the same error should I delete the $guarded?

Comment: Removing `$guarded` should not be necessary, as long as its empty like it is in your screenshot - adding `$fillable` should be enough. If it still does not work after adding your `$fillable`, could you repost what your code looks like currently?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of fillable is guarded returns opposite-list

The **fillable** property specifies which attributes should be mass-assignable. This can be set at the class or instance level.

remove **$guarded**

```
 protected $fillable = ['YourAttribute'];
```

In your model