# Laravel 5.5 Mass assignment exception error id on Laravel notification

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification

I have a project in Laravel 5.5 and I am using Laravel notification.

I want to send a *notification* to users when a product is added but when I use the notification, it gives me a `mass assignment exception error id`.

I think I don't have an error on the `User` model because my user model worked correctly before using the notification, and I don't find any model for notification until I add fillable id.

What is the solution for this problem?

these are the errors:

- [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZwFQ.png)
- [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG1E9.png)
- [Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNF2A.png)
- [Fourth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6wMH.png)
- [Fifth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9vo4.png)

Comment: you have mass assignment error when a product is added, so check product model for $guarded and $fillable

Comment: you should provide more details and code snippets for others to understand better. see this answer for mass assignment error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724253/8607640

Comment: @AnuratChapanond FIrst Thanks for your response but why should I check the product model? I did not use any of the products field in the notifications

Comment: like @Psycho said, it's the best I can imply from your short description of your problem.

Comment: are you doing any manipulation to the product or user model object inside your notification class?

Comment: @MAY yes I change my user model but it desnt have any error in crud operation before using laravel notification

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Thanks

Comment: @MAY please see the error images

Comment: Sorry, but these errors don't explain much, please show code for your user model and notification class from where this error is originating. that would help, thanks

Comment: @MAY thanks dear I solved it

Comment: @Akhlaqi can you please share the solution, it might help someone else facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @MAY because i have another notifications function in my user model for relationship and I think laravel also use notifications function, I rename my notification function and it solved